# Appflow keeps detecting project as capacitor not as cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor, ionic-appflow

I want to switch from a Capacitor to a Cordova Project, I uninstalled all capacitor plugins, used "ionic integrations disable capacitor", "ionic integrations enable cordova" and deleted capacitor out of the ionic.config.json. Appflow keeps detecting my App as Capacitor Project and thats why I'm getting Errors.

Would be nice if sb knows a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `capacitor.config.json` file